# How to prevent tkinter window from closing when I close Windows command console

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I open my CMD console to run my main.exe. I type:

```
python main.exe
```

My main.exe is a small window written with Tkinter. When I close the command console, my program ends and the window closes. I would like to terminate the console without terminating the program.

edit:

Saving my file as a .pyw doesn't work. Also, the console doesn't just magically appear. I'm not running the script in an IDE. I'm opening it with DOS. The program just closes when I close the cmd console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it with pythonw.exe.

The reason for this is that on Windows executables have a flag to tell the operating system they use a console or not. python.exe expects a console and if if is not already attached to one, it wll create one. pythonw.exe is linked with the GUI flag and does not create a console and if run from a console window will detach from that console.

This is why Tk uses wish.exe on Windows and not tclsh.exe with 'package require Tk' which would be ok on Unix but gives an unwanted console window on Windows.

If changing the extension to .pyw does not help check the program associated with this extension. For instance, on my Windows machine with Python 3.4 I have:

```
C:\opt\Python>assoc .pyw
.pyw=Python.NoConFile

C:\opt\Python>ftype Python.NoConFile
Python.NoConFile="C:\Windows\pyw.exe" "%1" %*
```

And pyw.exe does not attach to my console when run.

Comment: Perfect. Couldn't find this answer anywhere on SO.